# Keep getting "MetaMask - RPC Error: missing value for required argument 1" error while trying to get eth balance in metamask

Tags: metamask

I am here trying to get the balance of my account in Metamask with my checkEthBalance function by 'eth_getBalance' method.

```
let accounts;
let balance;

const connectWallet = async () => {
  console.log("connect wallet");

  if (window.ethereum) {
    try {
      accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_requestAccounts",
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  console.log(accounts);
};

const checkEthBalance = async () => {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    balance = await window.ethereum
      .request({
        method: "eth_getBalance",
        params: [accounts[0]],
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    console.log("Eth Balance", balance);
  }
};
```

But I keep getting this error:

MetaMask - RPC Error: missing value for required argument 1
{code: -32602, message: 'missing value for required argument 1'}

What I am missing out on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another param for the `"eth_getBalance"` method.

```
//Require block number or string: "latest", "earliest" or "pending"
params: [accounts[0],"latest"]
```

*note: The value returned will be in `gwei`, so you might need to convert it into ETH through utils from ethers.js or other methods.*

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I did see this solution in documentation, but the youtube tutorial I am following suggested that that is optional. But now after adding this param, it is working.

Comment: Everything web3 changes really fast, the best way is to always refer to the official updated document Alternatively, you can try to use ethers.js or web3.js, as they will introduce less breaking change and simplify stuff quite a bit.

Comment: Couldn't agree more.